# HashSet sort by property but set unicity with another

Tags: c#, hashset

I would like to know how can with a SortedSet, I can Sort by one property of my object and in the other hand set the unicity to another property.

Here what I have :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bonusSortedSet = new SortedSet<Bonus>(new ComparerByNumber());

        var bonus0 = new Bonus()
        {
            ID = "6479cc32-960d-4aa0-a62d-8c81e65085e8",
            Number = 15
        };

        var bonus1 = new Bonus()
        {
            ID = "8e8a9c1b-1889-4c4c-b039-b1dbe005719b",
            Number = 10
        };

        var bonus2 = new Bonus()
        {
            ID = "3453f78d-ce28-4ab1-a7a1-395063374f87",
            Number = 11
        };

        var bonus3 = new Bonus()
        {
            ID = "8e8a9c1b-1889-4c4c-b039-b1dbe005719b",
            Number = 12
        };

        bonusSortedSet.Add(bonus0);
        bonusSortedSet.Add(bonus1);
        bonusSortedSet.Add(bonus2);
        bonusSortedSet.Add(bonus3);

        foreach (var bonus in bonusSortedSet)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{bonus.ID} : {bonus.Number}");
        }
    }
}

public class Bonus : IEqualityComparer<Bonus>
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public int Number { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(Bonus x, Bonus y)
        {
            return x.GetHashCode() == y.GetHashCode();
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Bonus obj)
        {
            return obj != null ? obj.ID.GetHashCode() : string.Empty.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

public class ComparerByNumber : IComparer<Bonus>
{
    public int Compare(Bonus x, Bonus y)
    {
        return Math.Sign(x.Number - y.Number);
    }
}
```

}

The result is :

- 8e8a9c1b-1889-4c4c-b039-b1dbe005719b : 10
- 3453f78d-ce28-4ab1-a7a1-395063374f87 : 11
- 8e8a9c1b-1889-4c4c-b039-b1dbe005719b : 12
- 6479cc32-960d-4aa0-a62d-8c81e65085e8 : 15

I would have expect :

- 8e8a9c1b-1889-4c4c-b039-b1dbe005719b : 10
- 3453f78d-ce28-4ab1-a7a1-395063374f87 : 11
- 6479cc32-960d-4aa0-a62d-8c81e65085e8 : 15

Comment: Not an answer to what you ask, but it is _wrong_ that you have `Bonus` implement `IEqualityComparer<Bonus>`. What you want to have, is for the `Bonus` class to override `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()` which the class inherits from its base class. As your code stands now, `Bonus` does __not__ override `Equals`. But one instance of `Bonus` can act as an equality comparer for general `Bonus` instances, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't implemented any code to make the `Bonus` objects unique by their `ID` property, only by their `Number` property. Even if you did, such as:

```
public int Compare(Bonus x, Bonus y)
{
    if (x.ID == y.ID) return 0;
    return Math.Sign(x.Number - y.Number);
}
```

This can work in some situations, but is completely driven by the internal implementation of `SortedSet<T>` and is unlikely to work 99% of the time.

You can't have the set sorted by one property and the uniqueness dictated by a different one. If you want to track order and uniqueness on two independent properties, you'll need two collection objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your class implements `IEqualityComparer<Bonus>` which is wrong. You do not want a bonus to be a comparer, you want a bonus to be equatable.

Also, do not implement `Equals` by checking if hash codes are identical. Hash collisions will happen (but will be infrequent with a good `GetHashCode`).

Try writing the `Bonus` type like this:

```
public sealed class Bonus
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Bonus other)
        {
            return ID == other.ID;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ID?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    }
}
```

Then a `HashSet<>` with the implicit (default) equality comparer:

```
var bonusSet = new HashSet<Bonus>();
```

will ensure the set members are unique by `ID`. Then you can use Linq to sort the members when you enumerate them:

```
foreach (var bonus in bonusSet.OrderBy(x => x.Number))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{bonus.ID} : {bonus.Number}");
}
```

Comment: Thx but I want to sort my hash every time I add a bonus. And linq use extra among of power. Would like to find another way

Comment: @stix You would write your own `ISet<>` implementation. What should happen if you added a new member whose "unicity key" was new (i.e. new `ID`), but for which the "sort key" is the same as a sort key of an old member (i.e. its `Number` with `.CompareTo` to a `.Number` of another member in the set, gave `0`)? For example, if in your code in the question we added `var bonus4 = new Bonus()
{
ID = "aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa",
Number = 11 /* 11 is conflict */
};` You want it added or not? If yes, where should it be sorted in compared to the other one with `Number` also `11`?